# Optional leading segment (for version) in NextJS route

Tags: next.js

I'm working on a NextJS site that hosts documentation for a project. The project has many different releases, and I want the docs for each release version to be available.

I'd like to use a routing scheme like this:

- `/foo/bar` (page /foo/bar for latest version)
- `/x.y.z/foo/bar` (page /foo/bar for older version x.y.z)

Assume the rendering logic for `/foo/bar` and `/x.y.z/foo/bar` is exactly the same. I will just fetch a slightly different version of the data to pass as props when rendering.

I want the logic for `foo/bar` (regardless of version) to live in *one* place. But I can't use a dynamic segment for the version, because there is no way to apply any logic to match the segment. e.g. If I had a route `[version]/foo/bar`, the `[version]` would end up matching `foo` for the route `/foo/bar`.

This is not an unusual pattern-- how can I implement it in `NextJS`?

Answer (score 0):

That's not an issue, Next.js will check for static routes like `/foo/bar` before using the dynamic route `[version]/foo/bar`.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cndqj1?file=pages%2Findex.js